# GKE Jenkins via Bitnami Helm chart - how to update

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I've installed Jenkins on GKE using [Bitnami Chart](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/jenkins) and it is online.

When I want to adjust it using `helm upgrade`, Kubernetes brings up a new instance while leaving the other running (as expected), but the new instance fails to come up with

```
   Warning  FailedAttachVolume  18m                attachdetach-controller  Multi-Attach error for volume "pvc-b3d609b3-ec10-4966-8713-595702220c40" Volume is already used by pod(s) jenkins-9ddcc795c-vflvm                                                         
   Warning  FailedMount         11m                kubelet                  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[jenkins-data[], unattached volumes=[default-token-2qsvk jenkins-data]: timed out waiting for the condition
```

This error makes sense - two instances can't share storage.

If I take down the first instance, then it comes right back. If I `helm uninstall`, both instances are deleted including the storage.

What is the proper process to upgrade versions/update chart settings?

Comment: Is `kubectl delete deployments.apps jenkins` - which takes down Jenkins - the way? (Take down Jenkins then `helm upgrade`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the **deployment** of **Jenkin** first if you will delete the deployment other components will be there along with the storage disk which can reattached to the new deployment

```
kubectl delete deployments.apps jenkins
```

https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/jenkins#upgrading

and run command to upgrade the helm chart by updating the **value** file and using **--set**.

```
helm upgrade jenkins bitnami/jenkins --set jenkinsPassword=$JENKINS_PASSWORD --set jenkinsHome=/bitnami/jenkins/jenkins_home
```

Comment: I had hoped for an update method that wasn't so impactful to the service. I was wondering if changing the storage to NFS-type, which would allow multiple nodes concurrent access, would be safe. (And... how exactly to do it)

Comment: that's also good idea but i have not tested it. NFS will support the `read-write many` in that case you might need to do changes into the helm chart also. ideally it should have to work conceptually

Comment: yes, can use the NFS also : https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/kubernetes/#create-a-persistent-volume